# How to change path of partition in Grub2

Tags: grub2

I used to have a Windows 7 partition on my primary hard drive. But I recently moved the partition to the secondary partition, thus a change from sda1 to sdb1.

I know that I'm not supposed to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg, which is still configured to sda1.

Which file should I edit?

Comment: Just to clear things up, you moved it to second partition or second drive ? the letter after "sd" (sdA, sdB) is a physical drive, the number (sda1, sda2) is a partition on the same drive.... So, sda1 is the first partition of the first physical drive, sdb1 is the first partition of the second physical drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just re-run `grub-mkconfig` discussion here: http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3106368.0

Comment: note: you may have to edit the boot.ini on the windows partition to get it to boot